# node agent in glassfish v4.1.1

Tags: glassfish

I want to migrate an application from glassfish 2.1 to glassfish 4.1.1.
But not able to create node agent in glassfish 4.1.1

Already checked in admin console and also tried with command prompt as well with

command : **create-node-agent-na**

OUTPUT: **CLI194: Previously supported command: create-node-agent is not supported for this release.Command create-node-agent failed.**

Does anyone have any idea on how to create node agent in glassfish 4.1.1 or is there any replacement provided in GF v4.1.1

[glassfish 4.1.1 error:]

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish 3.x and higher no longer has a node agent. Administration works slightly differently; nodes are simply representations of the hosts where server instances reside. You can create a new `SSH`, `DCOM` or `CONFIG` node which governs how the DAS communicates with server instances on that node. The rest of the node configuration just identifies the IP address or hostname of the node.

If you create an `SSH` node (or `DCOM` node in Windows only), then you will be able to communicate with the server instances on the remote machine directly and start and stop them from the DAS.

If you create a `CONFIG` node, then the DAS has no way of communicating with server instances which are not running. When a server instance on a `CONFIG` node starts, it contacts the DAS to register itself as running, and then the DAS will be able to administer the instance over HTTP.

There is more information on how to do this [in this Payara Server blog post](http://blog.payara.fish/creating-a-simple-cluster-with-payara-server). Payara Server is derived from GlassFish, so all these instructions are valid on GlassFish 4.x as well.